# GTK Application doesn't run on windows

Tags: gtk, codeblocks

I'm a beginner programmer and I've looked around the internet for a solution to this and am still looking. I found someone in this forum with a similar problem, however he is using GtkSharp and I'm using Gtk+. Basically I wrote a program in CodeBlocks using GTK+ (initially I was going to do it on windows but it would not install properly and after several days I just gave up and installed CodeBlocks on my Ubuntu). However, now after I made a release of my program and am trying to run it on a windows computer it does not work. I believe GTK is properly installed on this computer (the demo from the read me worked after I installed GTK). Any help would be appreciated.

Also, if someone can give me a heads up on this: Would my program require for every computer using it to have installed the GTK library?

Comment: Hello. Please provide more details. You did recompile the program for Windows, didn't you? What is the error message when you try to execute your program on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you have to ship your program with the GTK libraries. Unfortunately packing is not so easy and all the currently available packages from gtk.org are outdated 2.16 or 2.22 and do not work well (themes are broken with missing icons and colors).

There are a few annoying bugs on windows like mouse enter/leave events not generated correctly.

If your program runs on one platform but not on the other it is very likely that you have an error in your program and because this is when you can see and feel the differences of the platforms pretty fast. So try to check again for GTK warnings.

And you have to provide more info, there is no way to help you with this information. YOu have to narrow the error problems to get help.

By the way, i wouldn't consider GTK a cross platform toolkit anymore, because it is only well maintained on Unix. Windows and MacOSX ports are a constant pain in the ass. That there is still no 3.0 binary distribution is just shamefull.

Comment: ...so why not help make one. People discussing it here: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2011-July/msg00013.html